# Is it possible that a usb drive manufactured 3 months ago can have data copied to it that shows the file last modified date before manufacturing date?

Tags: detection, usb-drive, usb, timestamp

I have some data that needs to be handed to a friend. I don't want to give the original drive (drive-1), so I plan to purchase a drive (drive-copy) and copy data to it. The data copied will still show last modified date for files to be the original date on the original drive (drive-1). E.g. the files may have a last modified of year 31 Dec 2017.

But the usb drive (drive-copy) that i purchase may be manufactured in 2018. So can it be detected that drive-copy is not the original even though it may show files' last modified date in 2017?

Comment: Why wouldn't you keep the copy and give the original drive if that's a concern ?

Comment: Because original drive contains some other data that's too large in size (250GB) and private. I tried to copy that 250 GB to a computer to see if I could get delete it from the original drive and give that, but copying that takes 10 hours and still shows size mismatch between original and copy to PC.

Comment: And explaining to your friend that this is a copy isn't do-able ? Anyway, I guess if you don't buy a USB stick model too recent, this shouldn't be a problem. Probably better to add random files then delete them before copying data on it tho, this should prevent a disk image to only show zeros where there should have been old files.

Comment: Can it be checked when the drive was manufactured?

Comment: It may depend on the drive, but I'd say probably not. I suggest running `lsusb -vvv` on it and find out by yourself.

Comment: It says "command not found" for lsusb on cygwin. 
I was wondering if there's any other way of copying 250GB off usb drive faster and cause for difference in sizes?

Comment: You could probably use dd or some low level imaging tool